# Does Apple News still support rss feed?

Tags: rss, apple-news

I am not sure Apple News still support rss import data.

I ask to Apple Discussion Forum but no response.

There is no section to add your rss feed url in settings page.

Does anybody have information about this issue?

Thanks.

Not: I saw this reddit issues:

https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/4xx1gv/apple_news_no_longer_supports_rss_feeds/

https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/4vjxj7/cannot_add_rss_feeds_in_apple_news/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure as "Apple-news" reader but as an "Apple-news" publisher you can still use RSS feeds to add your content to apple-news